# VSTS-TFS trigger build limit policy

Tags: c#, tfs, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have configured a trigger to execute a build of the project at TFS2018 Dashboard. The options that I checked are:

- Trigger status: enabled
- Batch changes when a build is in process: checked.

My problem comes when many people of the developers team check-in many changes at the same time (for example 4 check-in in an hour). Can be limited the number of build compilations for maximum 1 build per hour? Any other way to configure jobagent to do this limit per project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways you can define deployment approval this means you can have the power to approve the build or reject it to start. To do so :

Decide if you need pre-deployment approvers, post-deployment approvers, or both for an environment. Then open the appropriate conditions panel(s).

For a pre-deployment approval, choose the icon at the entry point of the environment and enable pre-deployment approvers.

[image]

Secondly, for the concept of CI/CD the build should actually run with every check in, to be sure that your test servers are always having latest code.

Comment: So, the solution would be to approve the build, instead of queue the build and control the time that it's executed? Thanks for your fast answer

Comment: this will cause you other problems, that people checked in and need their code to be moved and its not moving, which will give you more headache. its better to have control in this cases. if helped, don't forget to mark the question